# Installing a package to a separate directory by pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install a dependent package to a separate directory in my existing project as follows:

```
python -m pip install -t C:\Users\Mahdi\eclipse-workspace\
google-cloud-functions\com\mahdi\python\functions\gcs\dependency com.mahdi.python.file_igestion
```

but I get below error. Is there anything I am missing?

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement com.mahdi.pyhton.file_igestion (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for com.mahdi.pyhton.file_igestion
```

EDIT: per suggestion I could instllpackage by setup.py sdidst and I can see the package installed

```
C:\Users\Mahdi\eclipse-workspace\google-cloud-functions>python -m pip list
Package                  Version    Location
------------------------ ---------- -------------------------------------------------------
file-ingestion           0.2        c:\users\mahdi\eclipse-workspace\google-cloud-functions
```

but when I run blow command I still get error

```
C:\Users\Mahdi\eclipse-workspace\google-cloud-functions\com\mahdi\python\functions\gcs>python -m pip install -t C:\Users\Mahdi\ecli
pse-workspace\google-cloud-functions\com\mahdi\python\functions\gcs\dependency file-ingestion
Collecting file-ingestion
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement file-ingestion (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for file-ingestion
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Is this a package hosted on PyPI? If not, you'll need to provide pip the full path to where the package is located

Comment: No it is not on PyPI,it is a personal package, how to provide pip with full pat to the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a package that you've built locally you would need to use something similar to

`pip install mypackage --no-index --find-links file:///srv/pkg/mypackage`

You need to have packaged this up using `python setup.py sdist` first.

Comment: thatks for the comment, I can install the package on my local using python setup.py sdidt..but still can not install it to other directory using install -t command.

Comment: @Luckylukee You would need to provide both options `-t /location/to/install --no-index --find-links file:///srv/pkg/mypackage` together.

Comment: [code]python -m pip install -t C:\Users\Mahdi\ecli
pse-workspace\google-cloud-functions\com\mahdi\python\functions\gcs\dependency --no-index --find-links file:///C:/Users/Mahdi/eclip
se-workspace/google-cloud-functions
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (maybe you meant "pip install file:///C:/Users/Mahdi/eclipse-workspace/goo
gle-cloud-functions"?)[/code]...I got above error. My package is inside C:/Users/Mahdi/eclipse-workspace/goo
gle-cloud-functions and I am using windows.

Comment: @Luckylukee You haven't provided a requirement in that command. I think you want `python -m pip install file-ingestion -t C:\Users\Mahdi\eclipse-workspace\google-cloud-functions\com\mahdi\python\functions\gcs\dependency --no-index --find-links file:///C:/Users/Mahdi/eclipse-workspace/google-cloud-functions`

Comment: It gives me an error..Collecting file-ingestion
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement file-ingestion (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for file-ingestion